# VBA Pass value between subs

Tags: vba, excel, function, user-defined-functions

I am trying to learn how to pass values back and forth between subs.  I have created several macro subs that ultimately use the same lines of code over and over again between them.  To start I want to be able to look up/count the # of columns and rows.  This is what I have so far but it is not working.

I would also like to expand it beyond just cols to rows.

```
Public Sub main()
Dim lCols As Integer
Dim lRows As Integer

   lCols = countCols(Sheet1)

   Sheet1.Range("M2").Value = lCols

End Sub

Public Function countCols(sheetValue As Worksheet) As Variant
       countCols = sheetValue.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
   Exit Function
End Function
```

Right now it hangs within the function... Appears it is not passing the "Sheet1" into sheetValue.

Comment: `x1Up` should be `xlUp` lower case `L` not `1`.

Comment: Just FYI, I have answered this question before, see this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998773/set-a-variable-in-one-sub-and-use-in-another/17999208#17999208

Comment: If Scott's comment doesn't resolve your issue, please update the question with more details about what you mean by "it hangs".  (Using `x1Up` instead of `xlUp` would usually make the code crash with an "Application-defined or object-defined error", or just return an incorrect value, not hang.)

Comment: tip: type all commands in lower case like `xlup`, VBA editor will change it to `xlUp`. if you do not see the change then you have mis-typed it .... same with variables .... use upper and lower case when defining `dim lRows As long` but when you use the variable use all lower case `....value = lcols`, the editor will chnge it to `.....Value = lCols` .... if it does not change then you made an error in typing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few points:

1. It's better to declare row and column variables as long. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/6075259).
2. When you've declared variables `lCols, lRows` as `Integer` then return type of functions should also be `Integer`
3. No need to use `Exit Function` in your case. `Exit Function` is used to exit a function and execute the statement following function call. However in your case the function itself ends there hence exit is not required.

Try following

```
Public Sub main()
    Dim lCols As Long, lRows As Long  'declared as long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")  'change Sheet2 to your data sheet

    lCols = countCols(ws)
    lRows = countRows(ws)

    ws.Range("M2").Value = lCols
    ws.Range("N2").Value = lRows

End Sub

Public Function countCols(sheetValue As Worksheet) As Long  'should return long
       countCols = sheetValue.Cells(1, sheetValue.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function

Public Function countRows(sheetValue As Worksheet) As Long  'should return long
       countRows = sheetValue.Cells(sheetValue.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Comment: I should refresh more frequently..@c3nixon His code breaks because of missing `Option Explicit`and Sheet1 object. Is there any chance countCols can get Null or am I to careful?

Comment: @BitAccesser - If there's no row or column with data then `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` and `Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` will return `1`.

Comment: @BitAccesser If a function returns `Long`, is not possible to get `Null` from it.

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ What will cause an error if you try to assing a Null-Value to a Long. If `Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` can get Null you have to avoid assinging Null, by replaceing Null with a Long (or `On Error Resume Next` if you want to get shot ;-)): Iam not familiar with Excel functions, that's why I asked. btw is there no Nz() like function for Excel?